# ajax call returning null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have [this small script (fiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/et4083dh/) in charged for reading some blog XML. The problem is that it simply stopped working a few days ago. It seems the Ajax function is always returning `null`, even though there is data in the specified URL.

```
<script>
var toType = function(obj) {
    return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase()
}

var buildRSS = function (container_id){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://bloginstructions.blogspot.dk/rss.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result){
            var values = getEntries(result)
            console.log(result)
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var entry = values[i],
                    info = entry.__text.split("\n"),
                    title = info[0],
                    link = info[1],
                    date = entry.pubdate.match(/(.*) \d/)[1],
                    snippet = entry.description.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "").substring(0,350)+'...';

                var html = '<a href="' + link + '"><div><h4>' + title + '</h4><p>' + date + '</p><p>' + snippet + '</p></div></a>'
                $('#' + container_id).append(html)

            }
        }
    })
}

function getEntries(rawXML){
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    console.log(rawXML);
    var xml = rawXML.responseText;
    match = xml.match(/<item>(.*)<\/item>/);
    xml = match[0] || '';
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json(xml);
    json = json.rss.channel.item;
    return json
}
</script>

<div id="rssfeed">

</div>
<div id="rss">

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    buildRSS('rssfeed')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console to ensure there's no errors being thrown, and that the AJAX call is successful

Comment: It's successful, but if I do a console.log in the output of the function, it says it's `null`.

Comment: Go and check the `networks` tab, click on url and choose the `response` tab

Comment: Are you sure it's successful? When I run your actual code in a fiddle I get a CORS error: http://jsfiddle.net/5t0w5zxu/ --> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://bloginstructions.blogspot.dk/rss.xml. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access`. That would appear to be the source of your problem

Comment: In my server I have a script to generate the XML from the blog, so Cross-Origin won't be a problem, because I am reading fromt he same server and domain. Now, try switching the URL from my example to the one fiddle suggests: "/echo/xml". I know there will be a parsing error (if successful), but I am concerned about the ajax returning null.

Comment: I didn't say I was the owner. I just said I am trying to read the XML content of that blog and parse it with Javascript to a link related section I have in a website.